# Transcribe translated URL segments

Tags: multi-language, transcribe

Anyone know if there is a way to get the default (original) template-group/template segments from a Transcribe translated URL?

**Example:** If the default language URL for a template-group is "example.com/en/news/" and the translated one for spanish is "examples/es/noticias/", is there some way of getting the original `{segment_2}` var ("news") if we are viewing the spanish version (where `{segment_2}` is "noticias")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the template translations are all in place in the module, the default behavior of the segment_x variables should be to default back to their native ExpressionEngine template group / template names as defined in the template manager.

In the next version of Transcribe we're also introducing several additional early parse order variables such as {transcribe:segment_1} which will be populated with the url segment shown in the browser.

Comment: Hi Tom, any progress on this next release with early parse vars. We're using Transcribe on a 6-lang site and it's rather frustrating.